# How to get list of activities of DriveItem with msGraph sdk

Tags: c#, .net, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I have DriveItem that checkedOut by User1
with graph call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}?expand=activities
```

I have got my list of activities

```
{...
    "id": "01VMODTUDZVXS2MQJORNEYUTEPWOJ7VSB",
    ...
    "activities": [
        {
            "@sharePoint.localizedRelativeTime": "1|0|3|38",
            "action": {
                "checkin": {},
                "edit": {},
                "version": {
                    "newVersion": "3.0"
                }
            },
            "actor": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "displayName": "Administrator)",
                    "self": {},
                    "userPrincipalName": "csgdeveloper@csgdevelopment.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            },
            "id": "oFlcWLu82kiAeJgJAAAAAA==",
            "times": {
                "recordedTime": "2022-11-02T10:16:45Z"
            }
        ...
        }
    ],
...
...
    "shared": {
        "scope": "users"
    }
}
```

if I try the same in my project using SDK for C#

```
var activities = await this.GraphServiceClient.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItemId]
        .Request()
        .Expand("activities")
        .GetAsync();
```

I get an exception with message:

**Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'activities' on type 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'.**

Answer (score 0):

for API version 1.0

```
 var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
  new QueryOption("expand", "activities")
};

  var driveItem = await this.GraphServiceClient.Drives[XXXXX].Items[XXXXXX]
            .Request(queryOptions)
            .GetAsync();
```

Drive Item property AdditionalData i have got new key/value item with key: Activity and Value: itemActivity collection

Thank you

Comment: Is this your solution, or are you providing more information about the question? If it's the latter, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74288296/edit) the question and add it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when using `$expand`

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}?$expand=activities
```

The response fails with message

> Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property
> named 'activities' on type 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'

When using C# SDK

```
var activities = await this.GraphServiceClient.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItemId]
        .Request()
        .Expand("activities")
        .GetAsync();
```

it will generate the query above with `$expand` and fail.

When using only `expand` without `$`

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}?expand=activities
```

The response succeeds. The query above can be written in C# SDK like this

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
  new QueryOption("expand", "activities")
};

var driveItem = await this.GraphServiceClient.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItemId]
            .Request(queryOptions)
            .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
          {
            new QueryOption("expand", "listitem")
          };
    
var driveItemsPage = await this.GraphServiceClient
.Drives[driveId]
.Items[driveItemId]
.Children
.Request(queryOptions)
.Select(x => new
{x.Id,
x.Publication,
x.Name,
x.Description,
x.Size,
x.WebUrl,
x.Folder,
x.File,
x.FileSystemInfo,
x.ListItem
})
.GetAsync();
```

every Item from  driveItemsPage  has ListItem property

```
var isCheckedOut = item.File != null 
? item.ListItem.Fields.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("CheckoutUserLookupId", out value) 
: false;
```

so i get true if Item is checked out